# Zend Framework 1 query, ordering results by satisfied criteria

Tags: mysql, forms, zend-framework, filter, criteria

I've to extract all products from "product" table (DBMS: MySQL, Adapter: PDO), ordering result by the number of filtering criteria that are matched.

This is an example of raw SQL query (but I'll use Zend_DB classes and adapters):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM product 
    WHERE price < 300
    AND price > 100
    AND discount = TRUE
    AND used = FALSE
    AND type = MEAL

and a lot of other optionals filter criteria that end user could introduce from the UI.
```

All the filter criteria (where conditions in the query) could be optionally matched by the user in the form of the web app, and **the GOAL the my algorithm is to order the results from the most matching criteria product to the product that match at least 2 criteria.**

I'm using Zend Framework 1, and my question is:
Is there any Zend class that could help me in this particular algorithm?
If no, could anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

I've tried a crude solution where I'll compose the query considering all the possible combination of the criteria, but considering that there are a lot of criteria, the algorithm complexity increases so much, so I suppose that an alternative may exists.
Thanks

Comment: what about treating each criteria as its own 1/0 value within a case statement summing the cases and then ordering by it. `case when discount = true then 1 else 0 end + case when used=false then 1 else 0 end... ` as FilterCounts order by `case when discount = true then 1 else 0 end + case when used=false then 1 else 0 end... `  `having filtercounts > 1`

Comment: @xQbert excuse me, I have difficult to understand your answer... can you explain it in other way? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT P.*,
case when price < 300 and price >  100 then 1 else 0 end + 
case when discount = true then 1 else 0 end + 
case when used = false then 1 else 0 end + 
case when type = 'MEAL' then 1 else 0 end +
... (for each possible outcome) as Matches
    FROM product p)
Where matches > 2
Order by Matches descending
```